# Proving identity related to $\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How it can be shown that:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}=\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}-\left(1-x\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}}{2x\left(n+1\right)}$$

Where $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

---

My try:

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k}\\&=\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)x}\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n+1}{2k+1}\color{red}{x^{2k+1}}
\end{align}$$

Which follows from the identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}=2^{n-1}  \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (n \in \mathbb N_{\ge1})$$

But I don't know how to continue with that $\color{red}{x^{2k+1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]} {n \choose 2k} x^{2k}$$
Integrate both sides  Then
$$C+\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}-\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}=\sum_{k-0}^{[n/2]} {n \choose 2k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
Putting $x=0$ both sides we get constantant of integration $C=0$
Finally $$\sum_{k-0}^{[n/2]} {n \choose 2k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1-x)^{n+1}}{2x(n+1)}$$

Comment: clever approach (+1)

Comment: Thanks for appreciation.